# Who kept Roman peculium records?

Tags: ancient-rome, slavery, records, business-history, banking

This is effectively a Roman banking question but specifically with respect to the custody and record keeping of slaves wages.

[Dictionary of Greek and Roman Antiquities](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Servus.html) indicates a need for a lot of record keeping activity.

Slaves commonly had a peculium (money set aside for them) and there were debts back and forth between slaves, underslaves, slave owners.

Who was responsible for keeping the peculium records, the actual funds?

Were the debt records held in common with the peculium records or elsewhere, or were they informal?

Was there a public ledger or were the records only accessible to the slaver?

*- *Dictionary of Greek and Roman Antiquities, John Murray, London, 1875.*

Comment: A peculium was money a master *allowed* a slave to keep for his own use, although technically it belonged to the owner. So why would the State be interested?

Comment: @TheHonRose state? I’m not following.

Comment: Who else would be keeping the public ledger in your last para?

Comment: @simonatrcl It could be a business such as a bank. It is quite profitable to keep records, notice the tallest buildings in most any city is a bank. Taller than any church steeple.

Comment: Banks are profitable. No profitable bank makes account ledgers public - they'd rather keep their customers.

Comment: @simonatrcl your comment belies ignorance of the banking system. Credit reports are comprised of public debt records, banks share debt account information with reporting agencies (which are also very profitable).